# How do I use WordPress with HostGator?

Tags: wordpress, hosting

If I'm using the free version of WordPress to build my blog, would it be worth getting WordPress hosting through HostGator?

https://www.hostgator.com/managed-wordpress-hosting

The blog is very image heavy and it has some JavaScript so I'm worried about speed. I'll also be using a "comment" plug-in (disqus?). It's hard coded so no templates. I'm not sure if that matters.

Also, would it be worth upgrading to the premium version of WordPress for this same concern?

https://wordpress.com/pricing/

Comment: By free version of WordPress do you mean wordpress.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are effectively two platforms. WordPress.**com** and WordPress.**org**.

Upgrading to the 'premium' version of WordPress is on the **.com** side, which means they would host your site, whereas hostgator is a hosting company that would host the **.org** part of WordPress. You would have to migrate from .com to .org for the hostgator. But if it's a small project and you're inexperienced I would recommend upgrading on the current set up.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest differences you will see with creating a Wordpress site on a 3rd party host such as Hostgator vs. working within the Wordpress network itself is the catered support and tools you get.

If you already know what you are doing; creating databases, FTP access, resource management, you would be fine uploading an installation of Wordpress on any hosting provider. However, they most likely won't be top tier experts in using Wordpress and their main goal would be to keep the server that you are on running. Software updates and config changes such as php versions and some rules needing to be whitelisted would be the suspected level of support.

At Wordpress, at certain levels they offer cultivated aid (based on the sales page.) They also have hosting that is specifically tailored to work with Wordpress. If you are just starting, or even a super user that has WP specific needs, WP.com would be a good option.

Drake Customer Advocate at HostGator